# Spinner Can't Save Selected Value

Tags: java, android, spinner

before I explain to you, I told you, I've been searching in all of questions in stackoverflow and many webistes, so don't mark it duplicate or any negative acts. I've tried, work hard, and still stuck here many days. I need you to solve a simple problem.

I have a problem related about spinner. I've tried to use shared preference to save the default value, it work. But when I've tried every time to save selected spinner value, it fail, whenever I go back to previous page I can't retrieve the value I've selected before.

**FontSettings.java**

```
public class FontSettings extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner spinner1, spinnerLatin;
private SharedPreferences mMyPrefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mMyEdit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_font);

    // toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //this line shows back button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Display data size teks arab in dropdown list spinner
    Spinner spinnerBackgroundChange = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview_with_background);
    spinnerBackgroundChange.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    //save selected spinner value
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("spinnerValue", spinnerBackgroundChange.getSelectedItemPosition());
    editor.apply();

    //Display data size teks latin in dropdown list spinner
    Spinner spinnerLatin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerLatin);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayLatin = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerArrayLatin.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview_with_background);
    spinnerLatin.setAdapter(spinnerArrayLatin);
    // spinnerLatin default value
    spinnerLatin.setSelection(1);

    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
    addListenerOnSpinner2ItemSelection();
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SizeArabFont());
}

public void addListenerOnSpinner2ItemSelection() {
    spinnerLatin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerLatin);
    spinnerLatin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SizeLatinFont());
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} }
```

**SizeArabFont.java**

```
public class SizeArabFont implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private SharedPreferences.Editor mMyEdit;

public void onItemSelected (AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){

    ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#226169"));

    switch(pos) {
        case 0:
            Activity activity = (Activity) parent.getContext();
            TextView dgs = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.tekzArab);
            dgs.setTextSize(12);
            break;

        case 1:
            Activity activitys = (Activity) parent.getContext();
            TextView dgf = (TextView) activitys.findViewById(R.id.tekzArab);
            dgf.setTextSize(14);
            break;

        default:
            Activity activityu = (Activity) parent.getContext();
            TextView dgx = (TextView) activityu.findViewById(R.id.tekzArab);
            dgx.setTextSize(24);
            break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView <?> arg0){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
} }
```

**SettingsFont.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/reldoa"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sizedoa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Ukuran Font"
            android:textColor="#222222"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
  </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/reldoa"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sizelatin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Jenis Font"
    android:textColor="#222222"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:entries="@array/type_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/type_font"/>

  </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Font latin -->

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relLatin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fontLatin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="Font Latin"
            android:textColor="#226169"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Many thanks for your help!

**[UPDATE CODE] Update code with code given from @Pedro Massango**

```
public class FontSettings extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner spinner1, spinnerLatin;
private SharedPreferences mMyPrefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mMyEdit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_font);

    // toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //this line shows back button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Display data size teks arab in dropdown list spinner
    final Spinner spinnerBackgroundChange = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview_with_background);
    spinnerBackgroundChange.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    spinnerBackgroundChange.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt("spinnerValue", spinnerBackgroundChange.getSelectedItemPosition());
            editor.apply();

            if (position == 1) {
                int lastSelectedPosition = sharedPref.getInt("spinnerValue", 1);
                spinnerBackgroundChange.setSelection(lastSelectedPosition);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


    //Display data size teks latin in dropdown list spinner
    Spinner spinnerLatin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerLatin);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayLatin = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerArrayLatin.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview_with_background);
    spinnerLatin.setAdapter(spinnerArrayLatin);
    // spinnerLatin default value
    spinnerLatin.setSelection(1);

    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
    addListenerOnSpinner2ItemSelection();
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SizeArabFont());
}

public void addListenerOnSpinner2ItemSelection() {
    spinnerLatin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerLatin);
    spinnerLatin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SizeLatinFont());
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} }
```

I use this code, and it works for me. 
To save selected spinner value:

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor0 = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor0.putInt("VALUE", spinnerBackgroundChange.getSelectedItemPosition());
                    editor0.commit();
```

And to load or retrieve selected spinner value:

```
spinnerBackgroundChange.setSelection(sharedPref.getInt("VALUE", 6));
```

Comment: You should save the selected item when the user select it. On your current code, you are saving the first item, because your code to save it will run when the activity is launched  and not when the user select another option in spinner

Comment: Yes, I understand what are you saying about. Thats what I'm asking about. Can you write me a code please..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the selected item on your sharedPreferences use this code in your **onCreate(...)**:

```
final Spinner spinnerBackgroundChange = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinnerBackgroundChange.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt("spinnerValue", spinnerBackgroundChange.getSelectedItemPosition());
                editor.apply();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

To always select the previous selected item on your Spinner, just call this code, after you put the data on your spinner:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        final Spinner spinnerBackgroundChange = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        int lastSelectedPosition = sharedPref.getInt("spinnerValue", 0);
        spinnerBackgroundChange.setSelection(lastSelectedPosition);
```

Remember that you are currently saving the **selected item position** not the value.

> UPDATE (new answer below)

Adding another solution below. I notice that you have placed the code to update the position in a wrong place, so I just put that code on the right place (after you initialize the Spinner). Please try it and let me know if it does not worked.

```
    public class FontSettings extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner spinner1, spinnerLatin;
    private SharedPreferences mMyPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mMyEdit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_font);

        // toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //this line shows back button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //Display data size teks arab in dropdown list spinner
        final Spinner spinnerBackgroundChange = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview_with_background);
        spinnerBackgroundChange.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        // Code pasted here
        if (spinnerBackgroundChange.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
            int lastSelectedPosition = sharedPref.getInt("spinnerValue", 0);
            spinnerBackgroundChange.setSelection(lastSelectedPosition);
        }

        spinnerBackgroundChange.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt("spinnerValue", spinnerBackgroundChange.getSelectedItemPosition());
                editor.apply();

               // Code removed here
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        //Display data size teks latin in dropdown list spinner
        Spinner spinnerLatin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerLatin);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayLatin = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerArrayLatin.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview_with_background);
        spinnerLatin.setAdapter(spinnerArrayLatin);
        // spinnerLatin default value
        spinnerLatin.setSelection(1);

        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
        addListenerOnSpinner2ItemSelection();
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SizeArabFont());
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinner2ItemSelection() {
        spinnerLatin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerLatin);
        spinnerLatin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SizeLatinFont());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I've updated a code in FontSettings.java with code given from you, but still not work. Can you check my edit above?

Comment: Still not working. Still can't save last selected spinner value.

Comment: Hi Pedro, did you find the way?

Comment: At wich question?